# Does doing rdd.count() inside foreachRDD return results to Driver or Executor?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

For the code below, does the `.count()` return the value back to the driver or only to the executor?

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> dstream ...  
stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        long count = rdd.count();
        // some code to save count to Datastore
});
```

I know usually `count()` returns the value to the driver but I'm not sure what happens when it's inside foreacRDD?

For other related questions in the future, is there an easy way to verify if a code block executes on the driver or exeutor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations that give access to an RDD, such as `transform(rdd => ...)` and `foreachRDD(rdd => ...)` execute in the context of the driver. The mind twist that gets confusing is that operations on that `RDD` will execute on the executors in the cluster.

For example:

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    long count = rdd.count(); // the count is executed on the cluster, the result it brought back to the driver, like in core Spark
    RDD<> richer = rdd.map(elem => something(elem)) // executes distributed
    db.store(richer.top(10)) // executes in the driver
```

});

Comment: Just to confirm, so if I did `db.add(count)` in your example, the final value in `db` should to the sum of `count` in each executor, right?

Comment: @Glide that's correct. Anyway, `count` will not give you a partial result. It's an `action`  on an RDD and returns the number of elements in that distributed collection.